How do I make an Odoo addon model field of type HTMLField, render the context's value passed to it when updated from the admin view (not template)
In a custom odoo addon, I have created a model called AgreementTemplate. This model has a field of type HTMLField that stores the template used to display information. The problem is that from the admin interface when I edit this field and add a placeholder to access the context variable it saves it as string and not the variable.
This is the model class
class AgreementTemplate(models.Model):
    _name = 'agreement.template'
    
    name = fields.Char(string='Title')
    body_html = fields.Html(string='Body')
    version = fields.Char(string='Version')

From the controller this is how I pass that context
@http.route(['/my/agreements/<int:agreement_id>'], type='http', website=True)
    def agreement_detail_view(self, agreement_id, **kw):
        try:
            agreement = request.env['agreement.agreement'].sudo().search([('id', '=', agreement_id)])
            
        except (MissingError, AccessError):
            return request.redirect('/my')

        if agreement:
            pdf_content = agreement.agreement_report()


        vals = {
            'id': agreement_id, 
            'agreement': agreement,
            'page_name':'agreements_portal_detail_view', 
            'state': agreement.state, 
            'url': f'/my/agreements/{agreement_id}/accept',
            'action_send_mail': agreement.send_agreement_email,
            'pdf_content':pdf_content
            }

        return request.render('agreement.portal_detail_view', vals)

I have tried ${agreement.name} and {{agreement.name}} when I edited the body_html field but that does not work.
